# How to Add a Live Template (Code Snippet) in Pycharm for Robot Framework

Tags: pycharm, robotframework, code-snippets

I would like to add code snippets for my robot framework project in PyCharm.  I see from the PyCharm docs, the instructions for doing so are here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/creating-and-applying-live-templates-code-snippets.html

However, I don't see an option for enabling this in *.robot files.  Is this possible, if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your only choice might be to have this work in "other" contexts. That means, for example, if you were to edit some other non-robot file that wasn't one of the predefined contexts (python, javascript, sql, etc), it would trigger there as well. In practice this probably won't be much of a problem, unless you edit many different types of "other" files.

Comment: I tried "other" and couldn't get it to work initially.  In Pycharm Pref's under Editor, File and Code Templates, there are Robot Test Suites and Robot Keywords.  Enable Live Templates is turned off by default.  Turning them on resolved the issue for me.